# select scalar valued udf sql server

Tags: sql-server

I am using sql server 2008 rc2 and I have a question about naming conventions for scalar valued functions.  Specifically the following code works fine

```
select from database.dbo.MyUDF('arg')
```

but when I get rid of the dbo and try:

```
select from database..MyUDF('arg')
```

I get a syntax error saying that this is ambiguous.  I never use the dbo in the name of an object for tables, views, stored proc's or table valued functions and I never get this problem.

Why do I get this problem for a scalar udf?

Comment: Because..... that's the way the team designed SQL Server.... sorry, there's really no clear reason - it's just that way, and it's always been that way, and no - you cannot change it - just get used to it and use it.... Actually, it is considered a best practice to **always** use the `dbo.` notation - so maybe it's time you start to use that, for all your objects.

Comment: If you don't use dbo notation, then it means you're working with sysadmin rights. Otherwise you'd end up with [domain\user].Mytable for example on CREATE. **Bad practice**. At runtime, it attempts to resolve the user's schema before looking at dbo = slower performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First:

If you don't use dbo notation, then it means you're working with sysadmin rights. Otherwise you'd end up with [domain\user].Mytable for example on CREATE. **Bad practice**. At runtime, it attempts to resolve the user's schema before looking at dbo = slower performance.

Second:

Try using [SYNONYMS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

```
CREATE SYNONYM MyUDF FOR dbo.MyUDF
```

Note, Synonyms may require explicit permissions (but sounds like you're using sa or dbo anyway) and I've not used them with the database prefix so YMMV