# how to call a scalar UDF?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

i have created the udf to strip HTML from sql fields from here:
[link text](http://lazycoders.blogspot.com/2007/06/stripping-html-from-text-in-sql-server.html)

i am trying to run an update on my table where the defects_from_oracle.Description field has html

my sql is:

```
update defects_from_oracle
set Description = udf_StripHTML(Description)
```

where did i go wrong?
i get error:

> 'udf_StripHTML' is not a recognized
>   built-in function name.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432889/select-scalar-valued-udf-sql-server/4433042#4433042

Comment: Thanks gbn. I saw that post some days ago and I tried to find it for about 15 minutes with the SO search function without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you missed the dbo. prefex

```
update defects_from_oracle
set Description = dbo.udf_StripHTML(Description)
```

Comment: It's a design decision. Here in stackoverflow must be an older post about it.